# How to Execute Print Statement on Specific Timestamp in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I Just Want to Execute Print Statement in The Following Sequence

Here is My Code

Let's Assume The Following Time Stamp in Which Print Statement Should be Executed

```
t0 = 2022-01-25 12:00:00:000
t1 = 2022-01-25 12:00:00:050
t2 = 2022-01-25 12:00:00:100
t3 = 2022-01-25 12:00:00:150
t4 = 2022-01-25 12:00:00:200
```

With The Gap of 50 Milliseconds

Here is The Python Code

```
loop_start = 0
loop_end = 10

while loop_start < loop_end:
    print('Hello World')
    loop_start += (1/20)
```

So I Want to Print on Every 50 Milliseconds But According to The System Time Don't Want To Use Delay Here.

It will Only Print According to The Timestamp Mentioned Above

Please Help Me To Resolve This

Thank You.!

Comment: You're going to need to check the current time by using datetime.now() and seeing if it matches the timestamps you want.

Comment: Yes I Knew That But How to Check The Current Time? Because The Difference is in Milliseconds If I Put The "If" Statement For Checking The Time Then Most Probably It will Skip the Iteration if It wouldn't Match & I Want to Print on Every Loop Iteration But on Certain Timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've Solved This Through While Loop

```
loop_start = 0
loop_end = 10

start_time = (datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)).timestamp()

while loop_start < loop_end:
    start_time += 0.05
    
    while (datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)).timestamp() < start_time:
            time.sleep(0.001)

    print('Hello World')
    loop_start += (1/20)
```

So Here It will Check That Current Time is Equal To The Time Which is Required If Yes Then Print Otherwise Wait Till The Required Time

Still There is a Minor Delay In This But Acceptable For Me It Resolved My Problem

Comment: Make sure to update your question to let everyone know!